# Angular change detection Vs html edit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

So I heard angular change detection can cause lag in application if data from websocket is comming fast in huge qty. My flow is such that Data comes from socket. That data updates variable in component and change detection runs and html updates . What if I directly use variable that gets update from socket in my template? Will It remove change detection and improve my performance ?

-----------------------------------------------.

Comment: It will also trigger the change detection. You can control the change detection by changing the strategy to `OnPush` and using the `ChangeDetectorRef`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will improve performance, as the change detection will not need to be run each time the variable is updated. However, you should still be careful when working with data coming from web sockets, as this could potentially cause unexpected errors or issues if not handled correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain how come updating socket variable and using it directly in template wont trigger change detection?